# Lost notes on MacBook

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, notes.app

I have 3 different Apple products: iPad, iPhone and MacBook. I had written separate notes on all three. Somehow, the MacBook's notes ended up getting on my iPhone too. I didn't want excessive notes on my phone, so I deleted them. This then deleted the notes off of my computer as well.

I tried erasing the content from my iPhone and restoring back to the night before this happened - which didn't make a difference. The notes from my computer are still not there. I don't understand how the notes I originally wrote on my computer got permanently deleted through my phone, and I don't know how or if it is possible to recover them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Notes were being saved on iCloud on both devices.  When you deleted them from your phone, you were really deleting them from iCloud.

If you use "Time Machine" to backup your macbook, you can go back to the day before you deleted the notes on your phone and then sync your phone with iTunes to put the notes back on.

Then, on your iPhone, go into the iCloud settings and turn off Notes.  This will save your iPhone notes locally and keep them separate from the macbook.